Installing Pytorch for Windows 11 and AMD GPU
could someone help me out with my Pytorch installation? My device currently uses Windows OS and an AMD GPU. However, the Pytorch installation does not support Windows OS with ROCm combination. Only when Linux OS is chosen will the ROCm option be available.
Can I use CUDA toolkit in replacement of ROCm? Or do I somehow change my OS to Linux? Is there some way to by pass all of these and still be able to use Pytorch?
Any advice will be greatly appreciated!
I have tried looking for installation tutorials on youtube but they do not have the same OS and GPU combination as I do. (That is Windows OS and AMD GPU)

Switching to Linux certainly works, but seems to not be necessary.
If you choose this route, I recommend you start with Ubuntu as there is a lot of information available.
CUDA Toolkit however is only available if you have a NVIDIA GPU and will not work for you.
To get Pytorch to work on Windows, check out this stack-overflow question as it is quite detailed: How to use AMD GPU for fastai/pytorch?
